# Ember: Create a new record if none are found

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data

I have a route that pulls data from a REST API. The first time a user enters, there won't be any data saved, so I need to create the record with some default values. I figure I need to do this here in the route so the user can see my default values (which in my actual app aren't just null), rather than creating during the `save` action.

If, however, there is data in the database, I need to return that record. Right now I'm stuck and must not be doing something right (probably has to do with promises, but I'm not sure).

The error I get is:

```
Error while processing route: project.dates Assertion Failed: 
Expected an object as `data` in a call to `push` for star@model:project-date: , 
but was undefined
```

Here's my route code:

```
var project = this.modelFor('project');
var projectDates = this.store.find('project-date', project.id);
if (projectDates) {
  return projectDates;
} else {
  return this.store.createRecord('project-date', {
    project: project.id,
    start: null,
    checkpointA: null,
    finish: null
  };
}
```

The puzzling thing is that if I just negate my `if` statement to get the other return value (like so: `if (!projectDates)`) then I still get the error above, but it also loads up the model! I have confirmed that the API (or my mock API) is returning data in the right format, as an object.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using singularized model name in find and in createRecord('project-date' instead 'project-dates')?

Comment: Probably. I just edited. I had retyped from my actual code since the names wouldn't have made sense to anyone else.

Comment: Does your API return the data in proper JSON API format ? It seems that your call to find is returning data and actually causing the error because the `data` object that should be at the root of your API's response is not there

Comment: It does. For some reason, between all the bouncing around and restarting the ember server today, it's working now and getting the data from the mock server, but only when there is a record. If no records are found, an empty object is returned, but there's still *something* there and so `if (projectDates)` still returns true, when I want it to be false.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as I suspected, I could use promises stuff to solve this, just had to keep googling until I found something that jogged the right idea.

Here is how to set the model to the found record, or else create a new record:

```
model: function() {
  var project = this.modelFor('project');
  var projectDates = this.store.find('project-date', project.id).catch(function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('project-date', {
      project: project.id,
      start: null,
      checkpointA: null,
      finish: null
    };
  });
  return projectDates;
}
```